# C#, Oracle - How to store TEXT as BLOB

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, blob

I am coding in C# and I have following problem with Oracle DB.
I would like to store some TEXT in BLOB column but I do not know how.
Do you have any idea how to change my code?

```
String textValue = "Some example of text..."

oraCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE BLOB_TABLE SET BLOB_COLUMN = :data WHERE ID='123'";
                oraCommand.Parameters.Add(":data", OracleDbType.Blob);
                oraCommand.Parameters[":data"].Value = textValue;
                oraCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

Comment: a BLOB or a CLOB?  a BLOB is a binary data type and will expect a byte[] as the value.  you need to convert your string to a byte arary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must remove ":" while binding parameters. And BLOB is binary object, you should convert string to byte array. You should use CLOB for character large objects.

```
String textValue = "Some example of text..."

oraCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE BLOB_TABLE SET BLOB_COLUMN = :data WHERE ID='123'";
OracleParameter param  =  oraCommand.Parameters.Add("data", OracleDbType.Blob);
param.Value = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textValue);
oraCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```